# .Net, is it possible to step into a framework dll, while debugging?

Tags: .net

I have a Sharepoint DLL (part of Sharepoint 2010). I can reflect it using Redgate reflector. When I am debugging I would really like to step into the built in methods because it would provide great insight into a hard to track bug I am facing.

My question is more general though, up until now when I call a framework method, I just step over it and consider code on the other side a kind of black box void. To progress as a .net developer I need to start getting more into the internals.

So how it this done? Please use the Sharepoint dll as an example to make the solution generic enough to apply to any .net managed code library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came across a commercial product today that claims to allow you to debug assemblies even without the source code or debug symbols. I added a response with a hyperlink, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) useful. [The Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) also [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx) about it.

Comment: This is an awesome solution for the assemblies which MS publishes debug symbols for. Though it doesn't help with the SharePoint assemblies, it is well worth considering for general stuff.

Comment: @kbrimington, you cannot debug something you don't have symbols for it.

Comment: @Darin - Correct. Hence my upvote. I was only disclosing the limitation of the solution with respect to the OP's scenario.

Comment: @JL, only if you have the source code. So to step through: source code and/or symbols are required.

Comment: @Darin, I can export source code from Redgate Reflector, does this help?

Comment: @JL, yes, but then you will have to compile this code into an assembly instructing your compiler to emit symbols and then use this assembly instead of the original one. This could be too much of a work though. If I am not mistaken the [VSPro](http://www.reflector.net/vspro/) version of Red Gate reflector allows you to debug assemblies without source code using the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: What about VS2010 and VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug into **certain** framework source code.  If you [configure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) visual studio to allow debugging of framework source, then you can debug many of the core libraries.  Unfortunately, Sharepoint.dll is not part of the .net core, so you will not be able to debug into the Sharepoint source.

If you use a tool such as [ILSpy](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/marcueusebiu/archive/2011/04/12/ilspy-debugger-preview.aspx) you can debug into the IL, but that can get rather involved.

Answer (score 0):

I just received word that .NET Reflector is going all-commercial, which I find very disappointing.

**However**

RedGate boasts that their produce will allow you to debug another assembly even without its source code or debug symbols.

Here's their promo page: http://www.reflector.net/